# iOS change Localizable.strings at runtime

Tags: ios, localization, localizable.strings

I want to be able to update localized strings file at runtime, but is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441025/how-to-update-localizable-strings-from-app-by-code).

I thought about this:
My app uses web service. So I could have a web service that returns a .strings file and the file would be saved on the apps directory.

Now the problem: How can I change the NSLocalizedString to read from my file? Is it possible?

The app is not for apple store, so is not a problem if apple does not approve changing the app language.

Comment: Do you mean you want to localized strings at runtime?

Comment: @MikeD Yes, but I would like to control the file on webserver and return it to the application.

Comment: Are you targeting jailbroken devices?

Comment: @BjörnKaiser No. But the app is not for apple store.It will only be used in the company.

Comment: In that case you have to implement your own localization code and make it read a file from the apps' documents directory. This directory is writeable by your app and you can update the files whenever you want.

Comment: I guess the approach of @hypercrypt would be worth a try and should be the accepted answer if it works that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the data into a bundle in your sandbox and use `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle()` to get the proper localisation using the built in system.

Comment: How would you write to the bundle? It is not writeable after your app has been deployed. Or did I miss something?

Comment: You seem to be right according to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358044/can-i-load-a-localizable-strings-file-into-an-ios-app-over-the-air. Haven't tried it but it makes sense.

Comment: A bundle is just a folder really. You would specify the bundle in your sandbox, not the `.app` bundle (main bundle).